Capture error in variable Jenkins Maven Groovy
I want to capture error into variable so that I can sent it via chat notification.
Below stage in Jenkins pipeline
stage('Core Library Build') {
    steps {
        container('maven') {
            script {
                FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
               
                    // Capture the output inside a script block
                    def output = sh(
                        script: """
                            mvn -f product/lib/pom.xml deploy site surefire-report:report 2>&1
                            ls product/lib/target/ 2>&1
                            ls product/lib/target/site 2>&1
                        """,
                        returnStatus: true,   // Capture exit code
                        returnStdout: true    // Capture stdout + stderr
                    ).trim() // Trims any extra whitespace
                    
                    // Print the output to the Jenkins console
                    echo "lib Output:\n${output}"
                
            }
        }
    }
}

Getting below error

WorkflowScript: 126: Groovy compilation error(s) in script. Error(s): "Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;
solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...}" @ line 126, column 25.
script {


The error is in line 126. You posted a 24 line script. I have a feeling you are not telling the whole story here

compilation errors could not be caught inside the script itself. you can try to use catchError pipeline step to execute error flow https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure (not the fact it will work compilation errors)

@daggett either compilation error or some other due to junit basically build fails,
whatever error is, i just want to capture it into variable so that i can send it via chat notification via in post stage

you can't catch compilation error. compilation error means your code/pipeline not recognizable for groovy/jenkins. other errors you can catch with try-catch as described in a link i provided above.
